# Selenium Chromedriver not downloading to specified directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to download some data off of the [FanGraphs Leaderboards](https://fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx) using `selenium`. I was using Firefox do to so, but Chrome is a bit faster, so I was trying to switch over to that. With Firefox, downloading the files worked find, but I have been having trouble switching over to Chrome.

### Setting Up Chrome

```py
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.headless = False
os.makedirs("dist", exist_ok=True)
preferences = {
    "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
    "download.default_directory": "dist/",
    "directory_upgrade": True
}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option(
    "prefs", preferences
)
self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(
    chrome_options=chrome_options
)
```

### Exporting Data

```py
while True:
    try:
        WebDriverWait(self.browser, 20).until(
            expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable(
                (By.ID, "LeaderBoard1_cmdCSV")
            )
        ).click()
        break
    except exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException:
        self.__close_ad()
```

When ever I run the tests for my module, the CSV file ends up in **C:/Users/UserDir/Downloads**, rather than the **dist/** folder in my current working directory. I double checked that the **dist/** folder exists, and it does.

### Specs

- Python v3.9
- `selenium` v3.141.0
- Chromedriver v89.0.4389.23
- Google Chrome v88.0.4324.190

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and I fixed as

```
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", {'download.default_directory': f"{download_path}",
                                             'download.prompt_for_download': False,
                                             'download.directory_upgrade': True})
```

directory_upgrade may miss **download.** before.

Copy and paste this one

```
preferences = {
    "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
    "download.default_directory": "dist/",
    "download.directory_upgrade": True
}
```